# Missing R squared value from STATA output, what does that mean?

Tags: stata, r-squared, 2sls

I ran a 2SLS regression in STATA, and there is no R squared value given in the output (only a dot where the value should be). What could this be interpreted as? Is it missing because it may be a negative value? And does this imply the output is not to be trusted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $R^2$ has no meaning with 2SLS/IV regression since the residual sum of squares is not restricted to be smaller than the total sum of squares. So to answer your question: Yes, it might be negative. Stata supresses printing a negative $R^2$ when you use the `ivreg` command.

For a detailed discussion of this question, see the detailed answer in Stata's FAQs which can be found [here](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/two-stage-least-squares/).